# Elastic search for Laravel using Laravel Scout

Tags: laravel

I am creating demo for Elastic search for Laravel using Laravel Scout.I have used this site for refernce= https://medium.com/@samogorm/basic-search-functionality-with-elasticsearch-laravel-scout-6ac182c99cbf. I have install
 ElasticSearch , Java version to machine  and follow step of above link, but when I run command

```
-php artisan scout:import “App\Account”
```

I got error

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Class
>   'app\Account' not found
>
> at
>   /home/ashwinibhandare/Code/Elasticsearch/vendor/laravel/scout/src/Console/ImportCommand.php:35
>       31|     public function handle(Dispatcher $events)
>       32|     {
>       33|         $class = $this->argument('model');
>       34| 
>       35|         $model = new $class;
>       36| 
>       37|         $events->listen(ModelsImported::class, function ($event) use ($class) {
>       38|             $key = $event->models->last()->getScoutKey();
>       39|
>
> Exception trace:
>
> 1
>   Laravel\Scout\Console\ImportCommand::handle(Object(Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher))
>         /home/ashwinibhandare/Code/Elasticsearch/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:29
>
> 2   call_user_func_array()
>         /home/ashwinibhandare/Code/Elasticsearch/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:29
>
> Please use the argument -v to see more details.

I am not experience person, Can you please suggest me what is wrong

Comment: did you created `Account` class with package `App` ?

Comment: Yes Account class already created . You can see the class below
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Laravel\Scout\Searchable;

class Account extends Model
{
    use Searchable;
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'city', 'state',
    ];
}

Comment: I have solve the issue,It was some mistak

Comment: You should explain what was your error, I got the same trouble :(